# Send whatsapp messages from web page without opening whatsapp web

Tags: javascript, php, whatsapp

I want to send whatsapp message from a web page without opening the whatsapp web chat box. I know there are API's which are provided by twillio and chat-api for this functionality, but they have a pricing for that. I have seen many web applications which allows users to send whatsapp messages from their own applications without routing it to whatsapp web and that to after you register for their trial version for free. So how do they actually do this and manage to allow users to send whatsapp messages without costing them at all.

Comment: They do it by sending the number and message to the whatsapp api. You can try it easily. Go to this address and try. [link](https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=number) write your opponent telephone number with country code instead of number in link.

Comment: @xNoJustice you stated a link which everybody knows and this opens whatsapp web app in our desktop. Kindly read my problem statement again.